# name of the class where a function is called from at runtime

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm creating a really basic logger as a separate class with a method log(string).

Let's say I have 3 classes:
- A
- B
- Logger

I would have a logger object in each A and B classes. And I would do Logger.log("whatever").

I would like to have the name of the class it is called from in the logs. How can i retrieve this? (here it would be "A" or "B")

I would like not to have to pass any argument just for it if possible.

Comment: Have `Logger` take the name of the class in its constructor, and store it for later use. Have each of the two classes initialize their `Logger` member with their own name.

Comment: Is that the only possibility? I thought of that but there might be a cleaner way to do so

Comment: Could you transform it into an answer as it seems to be the only possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `Logger` take the name of the class in its constructor, and store it for later use. Have each of the two classes initialize their `Logger` member with their own name.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, called in a class function will give you the class and function in your log: -

```
 Logger.log(QString("%1::%2").arg(metaObject()->className()).arg(__func__));
```

Assuming that the class is derived from QObject.